# Bounds on determinants of Gram matrices of a certain form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \text{Mat}_{n,(m+n)}(\mathbb R)$ be a $n \times (m+n)$ real matrix, of the form $A = [I_n \ | \ D]$, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix. We are interested in the determinant of the Gram matrix $\det(AA^T)$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\det(AA^T) \geq 1$, with the equality holds only when $D = 0$?

The motivation of the question is to understand the volume of the rank $n$ lattice in $\mathbb R^{m+n}$, with the basis being $\{[1,0,\cdots, 0, a_{11},\cdots a_{1m}], \cdots, [0,\cdots, 0, 1, a_{n_1}, \cdots a_{nm}]\}$. If we regard the last $m$ entries as "perturbations" and drop them off, clearly the lattice in $\mathbb R^n$ has volume 1. So the geometric meaning of the question is, perturbations is those extra dimension does not shrink the volume.

It seems intuitively trivial but I did not find a quick proof. Maybe I just missed something silly. Any references/hints are appreciated.

Some smaller cases can be checked immediately. For $n = 2$ and any $m$, the assertion is true by the Cauchy inequality. For $n = 3$ and $m = 1$, I also verified by checking determinants, but naive approach will be too complicated if we test larger $(m,n)$ values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is true.

In fact, note that
$$
AA^{\top}=I_n+DD^{\top},
$$
and that $DD^{\top}$ is positive semi-definite, for which it yields an orthogonal diagonalization, i.e.,
$$
DD^{\top}=U\Lambda U^{\top},
$$
where $U$ is orthogonal, and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with each entry non-negative.

As a result, it follows that
$$
AA^{\top}=I_n+DD^{\top}=I_n+U\Lambda U^{\top}=U\left(I_n+\Lambda\right)U^{\top},
$$
with which it follows that
$$
\det\left(AA^{\top}\right)=\det\left(I_n+\Lambda\right)\ge 1.
$$
It is also obvious that the equality holds if and only if $\Lambda=O_n$, if and only if $DD^{\top}=O_n$, if and only if $D=O_{n\times m}$.